# If $A,B \in \left[ 0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $\sin{A}\gt\cos{B}$, show that $A+B\gt\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: trigonometry

The question was this:

> If $A,B \in \left[ 0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $\sin{A}\gt\cos{B}$, show that $A+B\gt\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Under the topic of trigonometry - Radian & quadrants. And this is not from a textbook. This is from a question paper.
I tried, but I have no idea on how to do this. Please someone help me out :(

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Even when you "have no idea", you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge or contest, give the intended audience. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it keeps others from wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand. ... In any case, the more you can show that you're personally invested in finding a solution, the more likely it is that others will become invested in helping you with the search.

Comment: Hint: Let $x = (A + B) / 2$ and $y = (A - B) / 2$. Then $A = x + y$ and $B = x - y$. Try using angle sum/difference formulas in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Besides what Blue said, you say "I tried", show us what you tried so that we can tell you where you got wrong/offtrack.

Answer (score 2):

First observation is that the $sin$ is monotonically increasing in $[0,\pi/2]$.
Therefore by our hypothesis and considering the addition
formula of sines we get
$$ \sin A > \cos B = \cos B \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \sin B \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - B\right)$$

Since $\sin$ is monotonic (note that $\pi/2 - B \in [0,\pi/2]$) we get $A > \pi/2 - B$ as expected.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin{A} > \cos{B}$$
$$\sin{A} > \sin{(\frac{\pi}{2} - B)}$$
$$\therefore A > \frac{\pi}{2} - B$$
or
$$\therefore A + B > \frac{\pi}{2}$$

This just makes use of simple `trigonometric identities`:

For the values that hold this inequality true, look at the graph below:

[image: Graph]

Here's another way to prove this inequality:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

See how the red block has disappeared in image 2... This is because the inequality does not hold true in image 2 and therefore function 1 does not work either (it will only hold true as long as the horizontal blue line is below the horizontal green line). Because `cos` complements `sin` (putting it another way: on a 90˚ angle scale, it is essentially the inverse of `sin`), the value for `A` changes as `B` changes and vice-versa, with the relationship: $$A > \frac{\pi}{2} - B$$.